# Future of "Logical Records" in SQL Merge Replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, database-replication, merge-replication

I am building a new application which will be using SQL Merge Replication over very poor networks.  It appears that the "Logical Records" feature would help significantly in coping with these network problems, ensuring that we can get complete 'entities' replicated one by one in separate transactions rather than going table by table.

However, the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152507%28SQL.100%29.aspx) states

> This feature will be removed in a
>   future version of Microsoft SQL
>   Server. Avoid using this feature in
>   new development work, and plan to
>   modify applications that currently use
>   this feature.

What I can't find in the documentation is a recommendation for what *should* be used instead to get similar functionality.  Does such a recommendation exist?  If not an official recommendation, what have people come up with on their own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following quote was marked as correct by Microsoft Tech Support on the [same question at msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreplication/thread/9b23ad9b-def3-4170-836c-4f218f4b03d0).

```
"... only the concept of Logical records is being deprecated.  
We can still define relationships using sp_addmergefilter @filter_type=1 ..."
```

If you read through the [documentation of sp_addmergefilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178584.aspx) it does appear you can accomplish the same purpose of the deprecated feature using a join filter @filter_type=1 (as opposed to the deprecated @filter_type=2).

Comment: Re-reading the msdn post I better understood what the poster was saying.  @filter_type=2 IS the deprecated feature, but @filter_type=1 is another way.  I've updated my answer.  Hopefully I didn't confuse the issue.